# Remove Constant from ConstantArray in LLVM pass

Tags: c, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to run a LLVM pass on some C code and need to remove `Constant`s from a `ConstantArray`. I have a `GlobalVariable` with said `ConstantArray` as initializer.

Deleting entries works using`F->replaceAllUsesWith(llvm::UndefValue::get(F->getType()))` and `F->dropAllReferences()` but that's not acceptable - I can't change the code using the array and it stops processing the array after encountering the first `NULL` value.

Is there any easy way to simply drop `Constant`s from a `ConstantArray` or do I have to create a new array without the respective entries I want to remove?

Comment: `setInitializer()`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid since it appears to involve creating a new array. I was hoping there's a way to modify the array in-place.

Comment: Why do you want that? I doubt this is supported by LLVM API.

Comment: Because simply replacing the `Constant` with `UndefValue` doesn't work in this case

Comment: To my best knowledge no such solution exists